# Magento 2.1 : I want to Add Dropdown on Admin Grid to Switch Between Different Grids

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, drop-downs

I have different grids in module. I want to add dropdown on the top of admin grid which allowed to switch between different grids like in image 
[image]

Comment: you can add html in your grid.php block file

Comment: i am using ui component. can you show it by code?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything as well. So for future reference, here is a very simple solution based on store switcher.

Add new block to layout of your grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Question\Grid\Switcher" name="adminhtml.question.grid.switcher" as="grid_switcher">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="links" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="grid_1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Order Grid</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sales/order/index</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="grid_2" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Invoice Grid</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sales/invoice/index</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="your_grid_definition"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create the block in `Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Question\Grid\Switcher`:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Question\Grid;

class Switcher extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    /**
     * Block template filename
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Company_Module::grid/switcher.phtml';

    /**
     * Get fully qualified link url.
     *
     * @param $url
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkUrl($url)
    {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl($url);
    }

    /**
     * Get active or first link for default display.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getCurrentGridTitle()
    {
        $links      = $this->getLinks();
        $currentUrl = str_replace('_', '/', $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName());

        foreach ($links as $link) {
            if ($link['url'] == $currentUrl) {
                return __($link['title']);
            }
        }

        return __(reset($links)['title']);
    }
}
```

and finally add phtml template `Company\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\grid\switcher.phtml`

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Question\Grid\Switcher */
?>
<?php if ($links = $block->getLinks()): ?>
<div class="store-switcher store-view">
    <div class="actions dropdown closable">
        <button
                type="button"
                class="admin__action-dropdown"
                data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                id="grid-change-button">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                $block->getCurrentGridTitle() ?>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="grid-list">
            <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
            <li><span class="item"><a href="<?= $block->getLinkUrl($link['url']) ?>"><?= __($link['title']) ?></a></span></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This new block should be added to all your grid layouts, link urls in the layout should be updated to match your routes. See `Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher` and `Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\store\switcher.phtml` for more possibilities.